# html image path incorrect

Tags: css, image

I'm somewhat perplexed by this.
..
The page im working on is located in

*www.gd-gaming.com/wordpress/*

However, for the background image to show, instead of putting it in

*www.gd-gaming.com/wordpress/images*

I've had to put it in

*www.gd-gaming.com/images*

Now, When I visit an additional page from the one im working on, (www.gd-gaming.com/wordpress/breakout-canidates/)

That background image dissapears. I cant understand why, I use the same code on a vbulletin website and the background displays everywhere. If I firebug it, it tells me the image didnt load, meaning the path is incorrect. I'm not sure where to put it though.

For actual reference.. 
http://www.gd-gaming.com/wordpress

http://www.gd-gaming.com/wordpress/breakout-canidates/

Code: `<div id="background">
       <img class="background" src="images/bgmain.jpg">
       </div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use absolute:

```
<div id="background"> <img class="background" src="/images/bgmain.jpg"> </div>
```

instead of relative one

Comment: EDIT: I see what you mean, done and it worked. THANK YOU very much my friend! It wont let me accept your answer for 9 minutes however =)